# Vaadin, where to put images?

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin

I have a Liferay project with Vaadin portlet.

I want to add icon to my buttons.

```
  Button search = new Button("Search");
  search.setIcon(new ThemeResource("img/silk/add.png"));
```

But dont know where i gonna put it? Now i put it in `docroot` directory.

**UPDATE**

No i try this.

```
  Button search = new Button("Search");
  search.setIcon(new ThemeResource("LifeRayVaadin-portlet/icons/add.png"));
```

But when i redeploy project in console get

```
09:34:05,773 WARN  [404_jsp:109] /html/VAADIN/themes/liferay/LifeRayVaadin-portlet/icons/add.png
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your portlet is looking for the icons in `/html/VAADIN/themes/liferay/LifeRayVaadin-portlet/icons/add.png`.

You could create a directory `icons` under `VAADIN` and call:

```
search.setIcon(new ThemeResource("../../icons/add.png"));
```

`ThemeResource` without any path will look for the file in `VAADIN/themes/yourtheme/` path and thus `../../` will get you (in this case) to `/VAADIN/`. I personally would never hardcode the name of a theme or a portlet in a project, because when it changes you have to go through every reference and change them.

Comment: I have not `VAADIN` directory in Liferay project.

Comment: Are you sure? I just downloaded Liferay 6.1 and found VAADIN directory in liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/html/. It's definetely required as it contains the widgetsets and themes for Vaadin portlets.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your images in $PORTLET-NAME/docroot/icons directory and call them using the Path

```
/$PORTLET-NAME$/icons/add.png
```

in your case it will be

```
 Button search = new Button("Search");

  search.setIcon(new ThemeResource("/$PORLTET-NAME$/icons/add.png"));
```

Comment: `$PORLTET-NAME$` it is name of project?

Comment: Yes, You can also call it as the folder name when it is deployed onto the application server. for example I have Liferay tomcat bundle, my portlet name is test-portlet. When I cross check in Tomcat/webapps/ I have it as "test-portlet" and I can access images as /test-portlet/icons/add.png.

Comment: I do it but nothing heppens. I see icons directory in portlet directory in Tomcat but not see it in button. Where i can fail?

Comment: As far as I know, it should be a relative URL. Can you please add a forward slash ("/") in the begining of the image path? currently it is search.setIcon(new ThemeResource("LifeRayVaadin-portlet/icons/add.png"));

but it should be search.setIcon(new ThemeResource("/LifeRayVaadin-portlet/icons/add.png"));